# Dynamic Loading Templates in Meteor

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I did a sample code using two templates.Those are :

1. Login Template - Login Form along with New User Button
2. Registration Template - Registration Form

Initially shows Login Template.So here when ever clicks a New User! Button in Login Template page then Immediately shows to Registration template page and hiding the Login Template page.In Reregistration Template Page Clicks Registration button if successfully registered then shows to Login Template Page and Hiding the Registration Template Page.I am new to `Meteor`. So Please see the below code & Suggest me how to do?

HTML Code :

```
<head>
  <title>hcare</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> login}}
</body>

<template name="login">
  <form id="login-form" action="action">
         <div> 
              <h2> Login<h2>
              <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enetr User Name" /><br>
              <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" /><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" />
             <input type="submit" value=" New User!" id="register" />
          </div>
    </form>
</template>
<template name="registration">
         <form id="register-form" action="action">
         <div>
              <h2> Create Account<h2>
              <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter UserName" /><br>
              <input type="text" id="name" placeholder=" Enter Name" /><br>
              <input type="text" id="email1" placeholder=" Enter Email" /><br>
              <input type="password" id="pwd1" placeholder=" Enter Password" /><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" />
          </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

JS Code :

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
  Template.login.events
  ({
    'submit #login-form' : function (e,t)
     {
          // template data, if any, is available in 'this'

            console.log("You pressed the button LOGIN ");
            e.preventDefault();
            // retrieve the input field values
             var email = t.find('#email').value
            , password = t.find('#pwd').value;
              console.log(email);
             Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err)
             {
                if (err) 
                {
                  console.log(err);
                  Session.set("loginError", true);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   console.log(" Login Success ");
                 }
             });
        }


  });

  Template.registration.events
  ({
    'submit #register-form' : function (e,t)
     {

            console.log("You pressed the button Register ");
            e.preventDefault();
          var username = t.find('#username').value
            , name = t.find('#name').value
            , email = t.find('#email1').value
            , password = t.find('#pwd1').value;
            console.log("password="+password);
            //var email = trimInput(email);
            // var isValidPassword = function(val) 
             // {
                 // console.log("isValidPassword() "+val.length);
                 // return val.length >= 6 ? true : false; 
              // }
             console.log("email="+email);
             var isValidPassword = function(val, field)
             {
                if (val.length >= 6) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  Session.set('displayMessage', 'Error &amp; Too short.')
                  return false; 
                }
             }

             if (isValidPassword(password))
             {
                console.log(" *** isValidPassword *** ");
                Accounts.createUser({email: email, password : password,username : username }, function(err)
                {
                   if (err) 
                    {
                      console.log(err);
                     alert(err.reason);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       console.log("Register Successfully");
                    }
                });
             }

    }
  });


}


if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function () 
  {
    // code to run on server at startup


  });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start to add the Meteor Iron-Router package:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router
read the docs and my be my tutorial, too (http://manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial).

Then you can easily set up two different routes, one for login and one for register with the Iron-Router.

You can then simply create normal links to switch from /login to /register.

The Iron-Router makes it really much easier, so I would highly suggest to take some time and really understand how it works (it is not that hard).

Good choice to learn Meteor, by the way :-)

---

To answer your question in your comment:
First of all, you should use the Iron-Router on windows, too. But without it you could render a template depending on the Session.

```
<body>
    {{> content}}
</body>

<template name="content">
    {{renderTemplate}}
</template>
```

Content Helper

```
Template.content.helpers({
    'renderTemplate': function(){
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: 'someValue'})
    }
})
```

Now in the content template should be the template rendered that is in your Session.get('currentTemplate').

You can then simply change the Session variable if someone clicks:

```
Template.login.events({
    'click #register': function(evt, tpl){ Session.set('currentTemplate', 'registration');}
})
```

Because the Session is a reactive data source and it knows, that the renderTemplate helper method depends on this specific data, it will re run the renderTemplate function. And now the registration template will be rendered.

Also make sure that you set the currentTemplate variable in your clients startup function to 'login'. (Session.set('currentTemplate', 'login'))
Otherwise nothing will show up at first and an error would occur.

This is not tested code, but it should give you a direction... And might even work ;-P

**Edit**:

You also do not want your input #register button to have the type="submit", make it type="button" so that the form will not be submitted! You can also add to your 'click #register' event-handler this:

```
evt.preventDefault()
```

Just to make sure the form will not be submitted.

Comment: Yeah,But I am working in windows system so Iron-Router package is not installed that's why i am asking.So with out Iron-Router what i can do?@DerMambo.

Comment: @user3213821 you should probably install it then, rather than figuring out how to replicate its functionality yourself.

Comment: I got this error i.e : `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object #<Object> is not a function` other than everthing is works fine.And this error came this line i.e **return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: '0'}));** .So please help me how to solve this error.@DerMambo.

Comment: What is use of `dataKey`?.@DerMambo

Comment: {dataKey: '0'} would be optional you could also just pass ({}). This is a way to inject data into your template. If you do {dataKey: '0'} you could access this in your template with {{dataKey}} and it would render '0'. Was just an extra example :)

The error can be the following:
Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')] has to be an existing template. So if eg. Session.get('currentTemplate') returns 'null' you cannot call that template. You could make sure if you add before the line:

if(!Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]){ return; }